# How does VideoCapture::read() modify an image declared inside and outside frame processing loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, mat

I am capturing video frames from a camera. Intention is to save the current frame `Mat frame` to `Mat A` when a user presses 'A' and save it to `Mat B` when a user presses 'B'. The problem is that eventually I get the last frame in all 3 matrices `A`, `B` and `frame`.

In the second code snippet I found out that if I put `Mat frame` inside the frame processing loop I get what I wanted but I don't understand why? Can anybody explain?

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
Mat A,B,frame;
while(true) {
    if (!cap.read(frame)) break;
    imshow("frame",frame);
    char ch = waitKey(33);
    if (ch == 'A') A = frame;
    if (ch == 'B') B = frame;
    if (ch == 27) {
        break;
    }
}

imshow("frame",frame);
imshow("A",A);
imshow("B",B);
waitKey(0);
```

correctly working code:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
Mat A,B,X;
while(true) {
    Mat frame;
    if (!cap.read(frame)) break;
    imshow("frame",frame);
    char ch = waitKey(33);
    if (ch == 'A') A = frame;
    if (ch == 'B') B = frame;
    if (ch == 27) {
        X = frame; // just last frame
        break;
    }
}

imshow("frame",X); 
imshow("A",A);
imshow("B",B);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: cv::Mat uses ref count, the = operator does not copy.

Comment: in c++ there is a .clone and a .copyTo method to solve that (both possible)

Comment: @Micka I am aware of ref count, but it doesn't explain why Mat frame is copied/cloned when frame is declared inside the loop and is not copied when the frame is outside the loop. It seems that VideoCapture::read behaves somehow different for these two cases. In the 2nd case it creates new frame, in the 1st it reads into the memory of already created frame. Why this happens?

Comment: a local variable within the loop is created new in each iteration, so it is not connected to any of your other variables and doesn't share the reference wirh any of those. Once you set A=frame; A and frame use the same reference, but in the next iteration the new frame variable will use a new reference counter.

Comment: @Micka it is shame that I didn't get it myself). Now I see it is obvious that a new frame gets created in each iteration. I confused it by thinking of it as i in for(int i=0;i<n;i++) kind of loops. Where i is visible in the loop only but persists across iterations...